# Facebook authentication with passport. Cannot read property '0' of undefined error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js, passport-facebook

I'm learning to add social authentication with Facebook to an app. Everything works fine, until I actually try to login to my test app with Facebook. Instead of being routed to the profile page, I get this error:

```
Cannot read property '0' of undefined

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Strategy.generateOrFindUser [as _verify] (C:\projects\Side            Projects\passyapp\app.js:16:19)
    at C:\projects\Side Projects\passyapp\node_modules\passport-  oauth2\lib\strategy.js:193:24
    at C:\projects\Side Projects\passyapp\node_modules\passport-  github\lib\strategy.js:174:7
    at passBackControl (C:\projects\Side Projects\passyapp\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:134:9)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\projects\Side Projects\passyapp\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:157:7)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

BELOW IS A SNIPPET FROM MY APP.JS FILE:

```
function generateOrFindUser(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done){
  if(profile.emails[0]) {
    User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { email: profile.emails[0] },
      {
        name: profile.displayName || profile.username,
        email: profile.emails[0].value,
        photo: profile.photos[0].value
      },
      {
        upsert: true
      },
    done
  );
  } else {
    var noEmailError = new Error("Your email privacy settings prevent you from signing in.");
    done(noEmailError, null);
  }
}

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
  clientID: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
  callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/return",
  profileFields: ['email', 'id', 'displayName', 'photos']
},
  generateOrFindUser)
);


//in order for passport to handle sessions you need to implement the two methods
//directly below
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(userId, done) {
  User.findById(userId, function(err, done) {
    //done(err, user);
  });
});
```

This is my User Schema

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  favoriteBook: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
    trim: true
  },
  photo: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  }
});
```

I hope this isn't a waste of your busy coder time.
Any attempt to help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `profile.emails` implies you asked for the `emails` scope, and not `email`

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: better answer

I'm guessing it's the `profile.emails` object (can't tell based on line number because your code is a snippet). Before that function you should have code that looks like this.

You need to ensure two things:

**1.**
When you call `passport.authenticate`, make sure to request the email scope, like this:
`app.route('/auth/facebook').get(passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: ['email']}));`

**2.**

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
  clientID: facebookConfig.clientID,
  clientSecret: facebookConfig.clientSecret,
  callbackURL: facebookConfig.callbackURL,
  profileFields   : ['id', 'name', 'email'],
  },
  function generateOrFindUser...
```

It's important that your profileFields array contains **email**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd already requested  the email scope like you suggested, unfortunately still have the same error.

Comment: was my assumption that `profile.emails` is undefined correct?

Comment: wait... why does it say passport-github in your traceback? do you have a line that says `var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-github').Strategy;`?

Comment: i'm also using the github strategy

Comment: Can you post the rest of `app.js` and your call to `passport.authenticate`?

Comment: the problem was with the fourth line on my snippet. I turns out it should be    `{ email: profile.emails[0].value }`

Comment: Hmm thank you for responding with the solution, but I'm a bit confused about it. I can see that you should have used `.value` to access the actual email string rather than the parent object, but it doesn't really explain the cannot read [0] of undefined, which implies `profile.emails` itself was undefined.

Comment: I think that error was first raising on `if(profile.emails[0]) {` since it's the 19th char on line 16. Was something changed with the Passport calls? Anyway glad it's fixed nonetheless!

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly, set your `profileFields` section.

   ```
   'facebookAuth' : {
      'clientID'      : 'your App ID',
      'clientSecret'  : 'your App Secret',
      'callbackURL'   : 'your Callback URL',
      'profileFields'   : ['emails']
   }
   ```
2. Now, we need to pull these details wherever we configure our passport code.

   ```
   passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
       // pull in our app id and secret from our auth.js file
       clientID        : configAuth.facebookAuth.clientID,
       clientSecret    : configAuth.facebookAuth.clientSecret,
       callbackURL     : configAuth.facebookAuth.callbackURL,
       profileFields   : configAuth.facebookAuth.profileFields
   }
   ```